# count visitor of pages in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching

How can i count visitor of pages in Laravel, prefer to use cache

```php
public function IndexShow(){
    Cache::put('home',0);
    $counter  = Cache::increment('home',1);
}
```

Comment: Technically, in your example this would be a request counter, not visitors. A visitor refreshing the page.. That still only counts as one!

Comment: Yes ! You are right, but please explain it to me how  count visitor of pages! or give me a reference

Comment: Is that everything you've tried so far? Could you start by listing all requirements, then providing some attempts to solve them? This could help to solve your problem, as nobody will write all that code for you on SO if you haven't even tried anything on your own

Comment: If you want to count the post by rang date or report of visitor in total month/day/week you can easily install cyrildewit/laravel-page-visits-counter is the best way

Comment: Your current code will work if you do `Cache::add` instead of `Cache::put`. `put` is gonna wipe out any previous value every time, leaving you with `1` always. `add` will only set it to `0` *if there's not an existing value*, which will let the counter increment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package then if google analytics is not an option for you. - https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker

They have thought through some things you would be seeking to do. You will end up with something like below.

```
//in your controller
$weeklyUsers = Tracker::users(60 * 24 * 7);

//in your blade
<div>
    <span class="h4 d-block font-weight-normal mb-2">{{ $weeklyUsers }}</span>
    <span class="font-weight-light"><strong>TOTAL VISITOR</strong></span>
</div>
```